# Control logging in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-amqp

I am using SimpleMessageListenerContainer for messaging and when a connection goes down my logs are filled with the below log messages:

INFO SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-634 SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer:1154 - Restarting Consumer: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-01-06 20:50:50.410 GMT  WARN SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-635 SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer:1163 - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Is there any way to prevent logging of such message numerous times. Instead is there any setting to control how often to emit such logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the log level for category...

`org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer`

... in your logging configuration to WARN.

Or, increase the `recoveryInterval` (it's 5000 - 5 seconds - by default), but that will mean it will take longer to recover when the connection is lost.

Comment: You didn`t explain how to do =(

Comment: Refer to your logging subsystem documentation. Log4j, log back, etc.